# Netsuite SuiteScript Gift Card issue

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am not a developer and our developer is away for a month to Philippines. We have a script that checks gift card balance. The same script runs in production fine but in sandbox is returning the error

`TypeError: Cannot call method "getText" of undefined (sfcc_gift_card_library.js#221)`

This is line #221

```
if (gcCurrency == gcCurrencyResults[0].getText('currency',null,'group')){
```

and below is the full function. When I added the **return gcCurrency** in the below function I get the result. The rest of the script has no issue and I am unable to figure out what to do next. I would appreciate all/any help. Sandbox refresh was done 2019 December and nothing was changed in production so really not sure about this.

function giftCardCurrency(giftCertCode, gcCurrency) {

```
// return the currency type, if not found error, if found but different than request, send back the correct currency

  if (!isNullOrEmpty(giftCertCode) && !isNullOrEmpty(gcCurrency)) {
    // return gcCurrency;

    var gcLoadSearchCurrency = nlapiLoadSearch('transaction', 'customsearch_gc_currency_check');
    var gcSearchCurrencyFilters = [];
    var gcSearchCurrencyColumn = [];

    gcSearchCurrencyFilters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('giftcertificate', null, 'is', giftCertCode, null));
    gcSearchCurrencyColumn.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('currency', null, 'group'));
    gcLoadSearchCurrency.addFilters(gcSearchCurrencyFilters);
    gcLoadSearchCurrency.addColumns(gcSearchCurrencyColumn);

    var gcCurrencySearch = gcLoadSearchCurrency.runSearch();
    var gcCurrencyResults = gcCurrencySearch.getResults(0, 100);

    if (!isNullOrEmpty(gcCurrencyResults)) {
      if (gcCurrency == gcCurrencyResults[0].getText('currency', null, 'group')) {
        return gcCurrency;
      } else {
        return (gcCurrency = gcCurrencyResults[0].getText('currency', null, 'group'));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks right to me.  If `gcCurrencyResults[0]` is `undefined`, then your search didn't return any results.  This block of code only shows one filter, but you're using `nlapiLoadSearch()` so the existing saved search may include other filters that are preventing any results from being returned.

Comment: never replied to your reply but it worked. Thank you so much Mike :)